# Undefined offset: 1 error in controller laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I've been stuck on this error for a little while. I don't know what to do anymore. I tried everything.

the error was starting on this:

```
  $hm->lat=$slat[$i];
```

this is my controller:

```
$students = (array)$request->stud;
$locations = (array)$request->studlocation;
$slat=(array)$request->slat;
$slng=(array)$request->slng;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($students); $i++){
$hm = new HouseMate;
$hmid = rand();
$hm->hmid=$hmid;
$hm->rId_fk=$renterid;
$hm->person=$students[$i];  
$hm->location=$locations[$i];
$hm->lat=$slat[$i];
$hm->lng=$slng[$i];
$hm->save();
```

}

and this is my view:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#dropdown").change(function() {
     var selVal = $(this).val();
     $("#textboxDiv").html('');
     $("#schoolloc").html('');

    if(selVal > 0) {
        for(var i = 1; i<= selVal; i++) {
             $("#textboxDiv").append('<input type="hidden" 
    value="student'+i+'" name="stud[]" />');
             $("#schoolloc").append('<input type="text" 
    name="studlocation[]" id="studlocation'+i+'" />');
        var input = document.getElementById('studlocation'+i+'');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    $("#slat").html('');
    $("#slng").html('');
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();

  $("#slat").append('<input type="hidden" name="slat" value='+lat+' />');
  $("#slng").append('<input type="hidden" name="slng" value='+lng + ' />');
         });
         }
       }
    });
    });
```

Comment: `dd($request->slat)` and show the result

Comment: I think your index is doesn't match in given arrays, once check it out both arrays count is same.

Comment: what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

`$slat[$i]` is out of bounds, which means that you must have some `students` without locations given. You will need to make sure that you only set the location for students which have a location and you set the correct location for each student. If this answer is not enough for you, then you will need to add further information about your `students` and their locations.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: @Cryptanalyst if my answer was not enough, then you should edit your question and describe your task so we understand it. So far I have absolutely no context about how your users are related to the locations. I can only see how your code assumed them to be related, but that was wrong, otherwise you would have not asked this question. Therefore I need to know what you need to achieve in order to help you further.

Comment: I was supposed to create a preference on my user based on their housemates on how many students and if where are they studying and as well as employees. And i need to get each long lat of each housemates to measure distance for my algo. And im still stuck as at data entry huhuhu

Comment: And what guarantees that $students[$i] is the i'th house mate and $slat[$i] and $slng[$i] is existent and matches $students[$i] logically? Do all students have locations?

Comment: so im gonna need an "if()" function?

Comment: @Cryptanalyst what is the content of $slat? What is the result of dd($request->slat)?